# Append children to document.body angular way

Tags: angular, angular-renderer

I have written code like below

```
this._renderer.appendChild(document.body, form);
```

This works fine. But i am directly accessing `document.body`. Is there a angular 2/4 way of access `document.body`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject via `DOCUMENT` injection token. This will give you the `document` object in Angular way (as you have said).

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document)
```

Comment: So i can then do this.document.body ?

Comment: Yes, but first make it instance of you class adding accessor

Comment: It throws compiler error for DOCUMENT and asks if you mean Document.

Comment: Import it from the `angular/common`